# How to create Custom Screener in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

> I am trying to make an indicator which has like 2-3 options for Long or Short
> but while making a screener pinescript is using only the 1st option and ignoring others

```
long1 = ema1 > ema2 and ema2 >= ema3
long2 = ta.crossover(ema1, ema2) and ema2 >= ema3
long3 = ema1 >= ema3 and ta.crossover(ema2, ema3)
LongAlert = long1 or long2 or long3
alertcondition(LongAlert, title = "Long", message = "Make Long Entry")
```

> The way this works in a single symbol indicator it doesn't work with a multi-symbol indicator/screener

> In multi-symbol screener it will only show results for Long1

> Can someone help with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to request data from other tickers or timeframes.

You can pass all your conditions in a tuple, or pass `LongAlert`.

One thing to note that is you are combining your conditions with an `or`. This means if one of the conditions is `true`, the rest doesn't matter. If all your conditions must be satisfied for the long entry, then use `and`.

Comment: if i need 1 ema above another and say ema1 > ema2 it will take 1 extra cangle to be useful so i need both options (crossover or greater than). With a set of 5 conditions there's a need for "or"